# What is the source for one sixtieth?

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, gematria-numerology

The rule of bitul one sixtieth or sleep one sixtieth death or dreams one sixtieth prophecy: How did we arrive at one sixtieth as the measurement?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babylonian_cuneiform_numerals It's a nice round number. Some modern poskim estimate rules of pikuach nefesh as being at least 1/1000. How did they pick 1000 and not 1003.2?

Comment: 10, 50 and 100 are also "nice round numbers".

Comment: @Maurice but only in a base-10 system. That's the whole point...

Comment: See my comment below as to why I do not think that they chose "a nice round number" for their numbers.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a direct answer to the question, but I think it's important to point out that 1/60 is far from the only "small fraction" mentioned in the Sources, so one should not jump to the conclusion that the Sages made it up.  We may not always know their reasons, but they did mention a lot of *precise* small fractions other than 1/60.  A *very* quick analysis:

> 1/40 and 1/50 in connection to Terumah [Bechorot 61a, Terumot 4:3]

> According to Beit Hillel (Terumot 4:3), one showing a “good eye,” i.e. a generous
> person, gives 1/40 of his produce as terumah to the Kohen and a bad-eyed person, i.e. a stingy person, gives 1/60 of the produce. Thus, the difference between the two people is one-third. Beit Shammai says that a “good eye” gives 1/30, and a “bad eye” gives one-1/50; thus, the difference is 2/5.

> How much is this little more? 1/20 of an egg. [Eruvin 83a]

> Tzedakah must be between 1/10 and 1/5 of income.

> A large step takes away 1/500 of a person’s eyesight. [Berakhot 43b, Shabbat 113b, Taanit 10b]

> If one carries a perforated flower-pot in a vineyard, if it increased by 1/200, it is forbidden. [Kelayim 7:8]

> Three things increase one’s waste, bend his stature, and remove 1/500 of the light of a person’s eyes. [Eruvin 55b]

> If a thief sold a stolen animal in a partial fashion, e.g., except for 1/100 of it, which he kept for himself... [Bava Kamma 78b]

> If a man fails to give him even 1/100 of his portion, let him realize that he is stealing it, not from the priestly tribe, but from Me. [Tanchuma, Terumah 4:1]

> The number of nations are 1/70 of the number of beasts that populate the earth. The number of fourlegged red blooded beasts on earth are 1/70 of the number of species of birds. The species of birds amount to 1/70 of the species of fish, which in turn are 1/70 of the number of different malignant forces, evil spirits, which in turn are 1/70 of the number of angels in heaven. [Chizkuni on Deut. 6:4]

> He must give the buyer additional amounts [geirumin], an additional 1/10 in the case of liquids sold by weight, and an additional 1/20 in the case of dry goods. [Bava Batra 5:11]

> 1/320 of the pool. [Mikvaot 6:11]

Comment: This list is a bit misleading. There's all of 4 or 5 round numbers that are being applied in slightly different ways in nearly all your examples. This proves quite conclusively that chazal indeed used nice round numbers wherever plausible. Usually either 1/60 or 1/100 for small bits, factors of the biblical 1/10 for maaserot, factors of 2 and 5 for extremity, and increments of 10 in denominators for ranges. Only when calculating fixed unit conversions did they have things like 1/320 and 5/8.

Answer (score 3):

They are not all the same thing. I am bring a source for the 1/60 batul beshishim as you referred to as "bitul". The concept is if a taste is diluted sixty times, it won't be detected anymore. The source for that is in [Chulin 98a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Chullin.98a?lang=bi). The korban shlamim for the nazir was eaten by a non-kohen except for the foreleg that went to the kohen. The concept of "taste being nullified" is shown here since a non-kohen may not eat from the fore leg but yet the whole animal was cooked together. So we see that the taste in the rest of the animal was nullified as otherwise the meat of the rest of the animal would be ossur to a non-kohen. The amoraim in that gemora argue whether one does not need to include the bones in calculating the nullifying the taste so really one needs 100x the taste (foreleg meat) or with the bones so it works out to be 60x (the meat and bones of the foreleg against the rest of the meat and bones of the animal). We hold like the latter.

Comment: This doesn't really get to the answer. How did they get 100 and 60? Why not 57 and 96? This just supports the contention that they are all just round number estimations.

Comment: I am surprised you're still pushing your comment above instead of a real answer. Your comment implies that they just picked a "nice round number" for each topic. That's a bit childish. My answer is showing that the 60 comes from somewhere and, true, they didn't use a micrometer to get to their numbers, but they used a good calculated estimate. We know that the circumference in the gemrah's time was calculated without knowing value of PI  (3.1415...) but they didn't just come up with a number of the thin air. I am not sure how your comment got upvoted.

Comment: What's childish is thinking that using a nice round number is equivalent to picking things out of thin air. I'm pushing the real answer. They didn't measure an animal leg with a micrometer or a macrometer. They had certain round numbers that they used and 60 was one of them even if we don't see it as so round. You're being mislead by thinking 60 is such an unusually precise fraction to choose that it must have been calculated. This is an important source but your are completely misinterpreting it.